# What is the "Hide and Seek" Garry's Mod addon in the "Plushie Hunt is terrifying… | Garry’s Mod FNAF" video by Gentoi?

Tags: garrys-mod, mod-identification

I would like to play the "Hide and Seek" *Garry's Mod* game mode or addon with my friends, as shown in the video ["Plushie Hunt is terrifying… | Garry’s Mod FNAF" by Gentoi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUm4zPtBTJA).

But when I search for mods or addons, I can't seem to find the game mode. Does anyone know how to play this game mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this Garry's Mod or FNAF? Which is the modded game?

Comment: This is clearly a Garry's Mod map/gamemode. @shao, when you you "search for mods", what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I'm reviewing this as leave open since it seems to be, despite the poor formatting, at its core a game-identification question with a valid artifact.